# How to make HTML container flex easier / scale navbar on mobile

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

This is currently what I have in my HTML code:

I have 3 of the "col-md-4" div's in the row, along with container--wrap in each of those, so that it fills the webpage with 3 equally sized containers. (div row is inside another div with class = container-fluid). When I adjust the window, the containers will stack on top of each other, but only after I make it much smaller (like 2/3). Also, on mobile, it does not stack at all and the containers are all really small. How can I make it so that these containers are able to stack (flex?) easier, and have them stack on mobile automatically? I also have a navbar that looks fine on mobile, but it remains small on mobile, just collapsed. How can I make it larger on mobile? Here is the navbar code:

cov19.cc (website) is an example of what I would like my site to do. The navbar is enlarged on mobile, and the container are stacked on top of each other rather than side by side. Thanks

Comment: Hello, please include your css code for the navbar.

Comment: I have no css for the navbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the First Problem, use **display:flex** for the row.I have also used media query so that when the user is on mobile screen or the size of screen is less than 991px, the containers will be on the top of each other.Please run it full screen and shrink the browser window to see the effect.

```css
@media all and (max-width:991px){
 
.row{


flex-direction:column;


}
.container--wrap{
width:98vw!important;

}

}     

.row{

display:flex;


}

.container--wrap{

width:33vw;
text-align:center;
border:1px solid;
transition:all 0.3s;

}
```

```html
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="container--wrap">
              This is one
              </div>
              </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="container--wrap">
              This is two
              </div>
              </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="container--wrap">
              This is three
              </div>
              </div>
              
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. It does flex how I want it to with this code, but the containers in the row become very skinny and do not stretch to fit the page when they flex, until I make the window much smaller like before.

Comment: Do you want these containers to fit the browser window size?

Comment: Yes, I would like the containers to always fit the window size.

Comment: Most Welcome :).I have updated my answer.Please check it.I have also added a border to view the width of container.

Comment: Hi I'm not sure why but it is still not working. Would you like me to take a video of what is happening? When I make window size half, the containers stack how I want them to, but the width is still very small and does not fit the window. It will stretch once I shrink the window even more. Also, the row is in a container--fluid, im not sure if that makes a difference. thanks

Comment: I was able to make it work, thanks so much. The only problem is that on mobile there is a  empty space on the right side. How can I fix this? if you would like to see the website is pumpkinchugger.github.io/rona20.live

Comment: Ok I will take a look and try to fix this for you.

Comment: You have made a very good website.For the problem of empty space, use this .container-fluid{ overflow-x:hidden!important; }

Comment: Thank you for the kind words! I will give this a try tomorrow as it is late now. Thanks!!

Comment: Most Welcome :) .I am very happy helping you.